# html fetched data does not appear in options for input list

Tags: javascript, html, drop-down-menu, datalist

I seem to be struggling with something very simple that I cannot resolve.

I have this input search bar which fetches data from an API which by itself works correctly.

For a sanity check, I have added in

```
   <option value="test1"></option>
```

Without clicking in the input field or enter "tes", test1 appears in the drop down which suggests this feature is ok

When I enter "Manchester Hilton" into the search bar, I have passed on id=message-1 ,3 and 5 into the datalist id=listHotels

This is called in from another script here:

```
            document.getElementById("message-1").value = data.destinationName;
            document.getElementById("message-3").value = data.destinationName1;
            document.getElementById("message-5").value = data.destinationName2;
```

However, there is no dropdown or selectable option for any of the hotel names:

The following is the code that I see appear on my website when I enter "manchester hilton" in the search box

```
    <div class="search-box">
        <form>
            <div class="flex-container-upper">
              <div class="search-input">
                <input list="listHotels" placeholder="Search for hotel name" autocomplete="off" type="text">
                <datalist id="listHotels">
                  <option value="Homewood Suites by Hilton Manchester/Airport" id="message-1"></option>
                  <option value="Tru by Hilton Manchester Downtown" id="message-3"></option>
                  <option value="DoubleTree by Hilton Hotel Manchester - Piccadilly" id="message-5"></option>
                  <option value="test1"></option>
                </datalist>
              </div>
            <button>Search</button>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
```

I am able to see the down arrow within the search input field but nothing appears to drop down automatically as it should.

This is the code that fetches the data from the backend:

```
      const hotelForm = document.querySelector('form')
      const search = document.querySelector('input')
      var e = document.getElementById("listHotels");

      const messageOne = document.querySelector('#message-1') /// Hotel Name / Loading text  
      const messageTwo = document.querySelector('#message-2')
      const messageThree = document.querySelector('#message-3') /// Hotel Name / Loading text  
      const messageFour = document.querySelector('#message-4')
      const messageFive = document.querySelector('#message-5') /// Hotel Name / Loading text  
      const messageSix = document.querySelector('#message-6')

      const debounce = (func, wait, immediate) => {
          let timeout
          return function () {
              const context = this, args = arguments
              const later = function () {
                  timeout = null
                  if (!immediate) func.apply(context, args)
              }
              const callNow = immediate && !timeout
              clearTimeout(timeout)
              timeout = setTimeout(later, wait)
              if (callNow) func.apply(context, args)
          }
      }
      hotelForm.addEventListener('input', debounce(() => {
          console.log(search.value)
          const query = search.value
          messageOne.textContent = 'Loading...'
          messageTwo.textContent = ''
          fetch('http://localhost:3000/autocomplete?search=' + query).then((response) => {
              response.json().then((data) => {
                  if (data.error) {
                      messageOne.textContent = data.error
                      messageTwo.textContent = ''
                      messageThree.textContent = ''
                      messageFour.textContent = ''
                      messageFive.textContent = ''
                      messageSix.textContent = ''
                  } else {
                      document.getElementById("message-1").value = data.destinationName;
                      document.getElementById("message-3").value = data.destinationName1;
                      document.getElementById("message-5").value = data.destinationName2;
                      messageOne.textContent = ''
                  }
              })
          })
      }, 2000))
```

Comment: Can you share the code that fetches data and generates the options?

Comment: added this code